# navbar-bottom in bootstrap does not position at the bottom with default mobile browser

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mobile, browser, navbar

While with all the other browsers*(mozilla last  version, opera last version and chrome same), the bottom navbar of bootstrap stay fixed and stick to the bottom of the mobile screen, with the default browser of android of my phone , but also the others, scroll together with the screen once if tap my finger on it, going up and down
you can view the issue here with your mobile

http://www.paolobergomi.it

is there a way to put it fixed for the default mobile browser?

```
navbar-fixed-bottom {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 1030;
}
```

thanks in advance

Paolo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding line:

```
navbar-fixed-bottom {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    bottom:0px !important;
    z-index: 1030;
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. i decided to take off the fixed bar for mobile and portable device as i set it static , so  i have more space to use for the images..i appreciated...anyway i will try